# Solving functional equation $\sin f = f^2-3if+\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations, entire-functions

I want to find all (entire) solutions to the equation $$\sin f = f^2-3if+\pi.$$ Using the identity theorem, I was able to show that if a solution exists, it must be constant. Therefore, all that is left to do is to show that there is some $a\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $$\sin a = a^2-3ia+\pi.$$ By plugging the above equation into WolframAlpha, I know that there must exist a unique solution (namely $a\approx .19+.78i$), but I could not prove so. Any help in showing the existence (or the uniqueness) of $a$ would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin a = a^2-3ia+\pi$ has *infinitely many* solutions $a \in \Bbb C$.

More generally, for any polynomial $p$, $\sin z - p(z)$ has infinitely
many zeros in the complex plane.

This can be shown in the same way as Antonio Vargas did it in [Solve $\sin(z) = z$ in complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388667/solve-sinz-z-in-complex-numbers/389149#389149) for the special case $\sin z - z$:

Assume that $\sin z - p(z)$ has only finitely many zeros. The function is entire and of order $1$,
therefore the [Hadamard factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Hadamard_factorization_theorem) gives that
$$
 \sin z - p(z) = q(z) e^{az+b}
$$
with a polynomial $q$, and complex numbers $a, b$. For $z = iy$, $y \to +\infty$,
the left-hand side is asymptotically 
$$
 \frac{e^{-y} - e^y}{2i} + O(y^{\deg p}) \sim \frac 12 i e^y
$$
and that is only possible if $\operatorname{Im} a = -1$.
On the other hand, for $z = -iy$, $y \to +\infty$,
the left-hand side is asymptotically 
$$
 \frac{e^{y} - e^{-y}}{2i} + O(y^{\deg p}) \sim -\frac 12 i e^y
$$
which is only possible if  $\operatorname{Im} a = +1$.