# Analytic map with two fixed points on a simply connected domain is the identity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:U\rightarrow U$  be analytic, where $U \subsetneqq \mathbb{C}$ is a simply connected domain. Suppose that $f$ has at least two fixed points. Prove that $f$ is the indentity map.

I am able to prove the theorem in the case where $U = \mathbb{D}$ is the unit disc (the proof uses Schwarz lemma, and is discussed [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86099/fixed-points-of-a-holomorphic-map-on-a-simply-connected-domain/%22Fixed%20points%20of%20a%20holomorphic%20map%20on%20a%20simply%20connected%20domain%22)).

The proof however skips the (rigorous) details of how the Riemann Mapping Theorem allows us to reduce from $U$ to $\mathbb{D}$. Any details are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Riemann mapping theorem, there is a biholomorphism $\phi : U \to \mathbb{D}$. Now consider the map $\phi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1} : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$. If $a, b \in U$ are fixed points of $f$, then $\phi(a), \phi(b) \in \mathbb{D}$ are fixed points of $\phi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}$. By the result you have proved, $\phi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1} = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{D}}$, and hence

$$f = \phi^{-1}\circ\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{D}}\circ\phi = \phi^{-1}\circ\phi = \operatorname{id}_U.$$

Comment: Thanks @MichaelAlbanese! This makes perfect sense.